# Is there any decent way to layout three 16:9 images on a 16:9 frame?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I would Ideally like to have them in a straight line, but then the images become too small.

So at the moment I have made [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSGC5.jpg) kind of arrangement, however I really hate how it looks. I don't mind cropping the images or the frame slightly, but the final image will be displayed on a 16:9

I have tried using photoshop to increase the resolution of the frame but there seems to be no appropriate layout that can show the images in a neat and pleasing way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to crop, sure.

**Couple examples:**

[image]

[image]

If you're willing to crop every single image, you could get a bit more fancier with it, but this also depends on the types of images you got and how they fit the frames in the first place.

P.S. Indesign has great frame fitting features.

- [Fitting in Indesign](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/indesign-fitting-graphics-to-frames.html)
- [Gap tool in Indesign](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/creative-sweet-tv/indesign-cs5-gap-tool/)

Comment: @nmu No problem. Another thing came to mind. A more entry level solution might be collage apps. Such as [Fotor](http://fotor.com/mac). It's available pretty much on every platform, even inside a browser.